# \hyperref: footnote links not active and color not changing

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, links

I'm using `\hyperref` and encountering two problems. First: footnote links are not active; second: I cannot seem to change the color of links or to go from colored links to links with borders.

Below is an example (using colored links, not borders):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb, natbib}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}

 \usepackage[pdftex, pdftitle={}, pdfauthor={}, colorlinks=true, urlcolor=green, linkcolor=green, citecolor=green, raiselinks=false, hyperfootnotes=true]{hyperref}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Sorry, here is, what I think, is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb, natbib}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}

 \usepackage[pdftex, pdftitle={Mongolia games paper}, pdfauthor={Daniel Rubenson, Peter Loewen \& Richard Sawyer}, colorlinks=true, urlcolor=green, linkcolor=green, citecolor=green, raiselinks=false, hyperfootnotes=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{hypernat}

\newcommand{\revertstretch}{\setstretch{1.3}}
\revertstretch

% THEOREM Environments ---------------------------------------------------
 \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}%[subsection]
 \newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
 \newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
 \newtheorem{thma}{Theorem}%[subsection]
 \newtheorem{lema}[thm]{Lemma}
 \newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
% \theoremcontact{definition}
 \newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
% \theoremcontact{remark}
 \newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
 \newtheorem{hypo}{Hypothesis}
% \numberwithin{equation}{subsection} % MATH ------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im} % \DeclareMathOperator{\ess}{ess}
 \newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
 \newcommand{\fn}{\footnote}
 \newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\h}{\mathcal{H}}
 \newcommand{\s}{\mathcal{S}}
 \newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}
 \newcommand{\J}{\mathcal{J}}
 \newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}
 \newcommand{\W}{\mathcal{W}}
 \newcommand{\X}{\mathcal{X}}
 \newcommand{\BOP}{\mathbf{B}}
 \newcommand{\BH}{\mathbf{B}(\mathcal{H})}
 \newcommand{\KH}{\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})}
 \newcommand{\Real}{\mathbb{R}}
 \newcommand{\Complex}{\mathbb{C}}
 \newcommand{\Field}{\mathbb{F}}
 \newcommand{\RPlus}{\Real^{+}}
 \newcommand{\Polar}{\mathcal{P}_{\s}}
 \newcommand{\Poly}{\mathcal{P}(E)}
 \newcommand{\EssD}{\mathcal{D}}
 \newcommand{\Lom}{\mathcal{L}}
 \newcommand{\States}{\mathcal{T}}
 \newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
 \newcommand{\seq}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
 \newcommand{\essnorm}[1]{\norm{#1}_{\ess}}
%%% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
 \begin{list}{}{%
  \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
  \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
 }%
\item[]}{\end{list}}






\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\singlespace
\begin{abstract}
\noindent Abstract
\end{abstract}

\clearpage
\doublespace
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}

\href{a_link}{a link}

An example.\footnote{An example.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Links are green and work. And when I change `colorlinks` from true to false, the links become red boxes. Your problem seems to lie elsewhere, please give us more and more precise info (see MWE link by Claudio).

Comment: It is better to not show just part of your code, but a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Sorry, here is, what I think, is a MWE.

Comment: Are you sure you can't leave out a single package or definition and still see the behaviour you describe?

Comment: BTW, it's still working for me. Just to be done with the "TV's not plugged in" kind of issues: you do use pdflatex and not some dvi-ps-pdf route?

Comment: Christian, thanks. So, it seems ctable is the problem. If I load it after hyperref, it works...kind of. The footnote link is now active and I can adjust the color of it, however, the color of the link from the \href command is always blue... Any ideas!? Thanks.

Comment: `hyperref` is known to have problems going along with packages that do something related to footnotes.

Answer (score 1):

The color of hyperlinks produced using `\href` is controlled by the `filecolor` key, so you can say

```
\usepackage[
  pdftitle={Mongolia games paper}, 
  pdfauthor={Daniel Rubenson, Peter Loewen \& Richard Sawyer}, 
  colorlinks=true, 
  urlcolor=green, 
  linkcolor=green, 
  citecolor=green, 
  filecolor=green, 
  raiselinks=false, 
  hyperfootnotes=true]{hyperref}
```

but apparently you want all the hyperlinks to be the same color; in this case, it is better to use `allcolors`:

```
\usepackage[
  pdftitle={Mongolia games paper}, 
  pdfauthor={Daniel Rubenson, Peter Loewen \& Richard Sawyer}, 
  colorlinks=true, 
  allcolors=green, 
  raiselinks=false, 
  hyperfootnotes=true]{hyperref}
```

A complete example incorporating some of your code (i changed the value of `paperheight` just for the example):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb, natbib}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in,
paperheight=8cm% just for the example
]{geometry}

\usepackage[
  pdftitle={Mongolia games paper}, 
  pdfauthor={Daniel Rubenson, Peter Loewen \& Richard Sawyer}, 
  colorlinks=true, 
  urlcolor=green, 
  linkcolor=green, 
  citecolor=green, 
  filecolor=green, 
  raiselinks=false, 
  hyperfootnotes=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{hypernat}

\newcommand{\revertstretch}{\setstretch{1.3}}
\revertstretch

\begin{document}

\href{a_link}{a link}

An example.\footnote{An example.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding the issue with footnote hyperlink, it is a well known fact that `hyperref` might not cooperate well with footnotes; here's a little note about the `hyperfootnotes` option, taken from `hyperref`'s documentation:

[image]